# Unique value count based on two column group pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Unique value count based on two-columns group

Dataframe is like

```
    col1 col2  col3  Col4  Col5....
-----------------------------------
 1:  A    S1   X110 
 2:  A    S1   X110 
 3:  A    S2   X212 
 4:  B    S3   X311 
 5:  A    S2   X212 
 6:  A    S1   X150 
 7:  B    S3   X311    
 8:  C    S4   X222    
 9:  C    S4   X222    
10:  C    S4   X222    
11:  A    S1   X150 
12:  A    S2   X200
13:  A    S2   X211
14:  B    S3   X311
15:  B    S3   X311


data = {'Col1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'Col2':['S1','S1','S2','S3','S2','S1','S3','S4','S4','S4','S1','S2','S2','S3','S3'],
         'Col3':['X110','X110','X212','X311','X212','X150','X311','X222','X222','X222','X150',
                     'X200','X211','X311','X311'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to count unique (distinct) combinations of col1 and col2 for each value of col3.

A & S2 have three unique combinations X212, X200, X211.

so the result for that combination is 3.

Expected output is

```
    col1 col2  Count
--------------------------
 1:  A    S1     2 
 2:  A    S2     3
 3:  B    S3     1
 5:  C    S4     1
```

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3']).size().reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for the answers, But sorry I want to ask something else(my bad), now the question updated correctly. please check it.

Comment: changed dupe, please check.

Comment: @jezrael, I want to displayed the unique count of col3 for combination of col1 and col 2

Comment: `df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3'].nunique().reset_index(name='Count')`